# Escape Characters for MODE CON

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking to write the "MODE CON:" command to another batch file, but the batch only echoes the following to the console instead:
`MODE CON: COLS=40 LINES=`

I'm looking for a method to escape this output. The current command is inside of "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" and is written:

`echo:MODE CON: COLS=40 LINES=5>>"Path\Fetch.bat"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is that a number immediately preceding the redirection operators will change which stream is redirected.

A number of options:

1. Add a space before the redirection operator:

   ```
   echo:MODE CON: COLS=40 LINES=5 >>"Path\Fetch.bat"
   ```

   This will add a trailing space to the line, but that shouldn't matter here.
2. [Place the redirection operator somewhere else on the line](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170801-00/?p=96725):

   ```
   >>"Path\Fetch.bat" echo:MODE CON: COLS=40 LINES=5
   ```
3. Surround the command with parentheses and apply the redirection outside of them:

   ```
   (echo:MODE CON: COLS=40 LINES=5)>>"Path\Fetch.bat"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>"Path\Fetch.bat" echo:MODE CON: COLS=40 LINES=5
```

A digit directly before a redirector redirects *that* logical device # (0=stdin, 1-stdout,2=stderr, others unassigned)